# file:// protocol in Excel and Word - Hyperlink URL changes

Tags: microsoft-excel, url, hyperlink

Clicking on `file:///D:/UpToDate/contents/mobipreview.htm?3/4/3141` in Microsoft Excel opens an URL in a browser but omits the `file:///` and `?3/4/3141` portions from the hyperlink thus the resource doesn't open in the browser.

How can I make Excel to open the `file://` protocol URLs without modifying the links?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define "ForceShellExecute" in registry so office will not manipulate the link. but it has some limitations:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/emeaoffice/archive/2013/06/13/impact-of-using-forceshellexecute-1-in-office-2007-2010-and-2013.aspx

from the article:

"For different reasons (such as "Cannot locate the Internet server or proxy server"), your company may find that it has a need of changing the way that Office opens links, and force Office to use the Windows way of opening links. To achieve this, you will use this registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet
and a Reg_Dword called ForceShellExecute with value 1
(N.B. this key refers to 9.0 for all versions of Office)"

This will make Office use Windows way of linking instead of Office way of linking. So it will basically be the same as if the user opened the link by Start – Run – Paste the link – Enter. There are sine known behavior changes and problems you may see when setting this key, so that you can make a meaningful decision about if you should use it or not. (see link)

Comment: Please include the important parts of that article in your answer in case the link breaks.

Comment: @BenN done, i'll not add the risks though.

Comment: BTW this doesn't work for newer office versions it seems